# How to jump back to previous assembly code position in perf-annotate?

Tags: perf

While using perf-annotate, I can hit `Enter` to jump to target assembly code position that `jmp`/`jne`/`je` points to, I want to know how can I jump back? I'm using perf `4.15.18`.